# Check if YouTube streaming video is live or not

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to check if a (public) YouTube streaming video is live or not.
I tried to use YouTube Player JavaScript API, but I can't find anything that may help me to find out if the streaming is already started or not.

I saw the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/), but I can't find JavaScript examples of using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) request and from response look at [actualStartTime](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.actualStartTime)

You can use this [line for example](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/my_uploads.js#L34), just modify it to videos.list